# How to reference table column header name and table row number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to populate a new table in a new worksheet with data from an existing table in a different worksheet. I need to reference the column header name because the positions of the columns may change.

I currently have this:

```
=TableName[@[ColumnHeaderName]]
```

This works but the problem is when I try to sort any of the columns in the new table, it doesn't sort because it is referencing the same row in the existing table. I'm guessing I need to reference the column name and row number, but when I try "=TableName[@[ColumnHeaderName]] 2:2" it displays #VALUE!.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are working with excel tables (i.e. `ListObjects`).
The formula:

```
=TableName[@[ColumnHeaderName]]
```

refers to the
-  Table: `TableName`
-  Column: `ColumnHeaderName`
-  Row: `Row` of the cell where the formula is entered from the `Worksheet` where the `Table` is located.

Therefore if the `TableName` header is located at row 6 of `Sheet1` and the formula is entered in row 8 of `Sheet2` it will return the value in column `ColumnHeaderName`, row 8 of `Sheet1` which is the row 2 of the `Table.Body` (e.i. `DataBodyRange`)

To return the first value in column `ColumnHeaderName` of the `TableName`  use this formula:

```
=INDEX(TableName[ColumnHeaderName],1)
```

`TableName[@[ColumnHeaderName]]` refers to the same row of the table and
`TableName[ColumnHeaderName]` refers to the entire column.
Also, any of the above formulas exclude the header of the Table.
To refer to the header use:

```
=TableName[[#Headers],[ColumnHeaderName]]
```

if you want to refer the entire header use:

```
=TableName[#Headers]
```

Since you are entering the formula in another excel table, lets named it `Table2`, in order to have the row number dynamically updated enter this formula:

```
=INDEX(TableName[ColumnHeaderName],ROW()-ROW(Table2[#Headers]))
```

Comment: Thanks, that has worked! The only issue is that the row number doesn't update (+1 each time) when I pull down to auto fill the rest of the table. Will I need to enter each one manually?

Comment: That dynamically updates, but acts exactly like my original cell reference. I can't sort the columns

Comment: Well, the problem is *How to reference table column header name and table row number?*, which is solved with the formula provided. Now if you want to sort the data and keep the values, you need to either copy the formulas as values or use a working column to maintain the row reference fixed, but that is something that happens with any other formula, as must of the time when retrieving values from other sheets the formulas will update once they are sorted.

Comment: @Chris I wonder if you are using the second table just to sort the data in the first table, is that is the case I suggest to use a pivot table.

Comment: No it's not for sorting, I can sort the source table just fine. The source table is scraped from a website and will be updated weekly. The second table is for me to use the data in the first table for my own formulas.